# How to define pthread and mutex lock in C files that depend on each other?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I’m new to pthread and mutex lock. I used them before but in a single file (main.c that creates the threads and locks are in the same file as functions and memory that use the locks). How to define mutex lock in C files that depend on each other? Ideally, I wish not to change the current structure.

```
main.c   // create threads, include `file1.h`
file1.h  
file1.c  // include `file1.h` and `lib.h`, extern a memory defined in `lib.c`
lib.h  
lib.c   // include `lib.h`, contain functions that malloc and dealloc memory, which need to be accessed by many threads
```

Comment: Which file is the mutex defined in?

Comment: I added a main.h, and defined mutex there. I’m thinking lib.c can just import main.h and use it. Will it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the mutex in one of the `.c` files:

```
pthread_mutex_t mux;
```

and then you need to forward-declare it in one of the `.h` files:

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mux;
```

The normal convention is that you put the forward declaration in the `.h` file corresponding to the `.c` file, but there's no reason you couldn't put it in a different `.h` file; you just have to remember which `.h` to include.  Make sure you include the `.h` file where the variable is defined and everywhere that it is used.